# HDMI Output to Monitor not Working on Ubuntu Desktop 23.04

Tags: hdmi, intel, external-monitor

I've been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now... hoping someone here can help me out and point me to next steps I can try.

I bought a new HP laptop ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BTFJZ9BQ)) and installed Ubuntu 22.10 on it. There were some missing network + Bluetooth drivers in the 5.19 kernel which I built and installed. Once Ubuntu 23.04 came out I upgraded since the network + Bluetooth drivers are in kernel 6.2 out of the box.

The one piece that's (still) missing is plugging in a monitor. I've tried plugging a monitor into both the HDMI and USB-C ports on my machine but the monitor never receives anything (the monitor works with both a Mac and another older Ubuntu 20.04 laptop). The "Displays" setting (click Activities in the top left and type in "Displays") also doesn't recognize that the monitor was plugged in.

I don't see the same "UNCLAIMED" error messages from `lshw` for the graphics hardware that I was seeing for the network driver (so perhaps its not a graphics driver issue?). Just in case it was, I followed the steps described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/1371#issuecomment-1364712624) to see if I saw any change, but haven't had any joy yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions for next steps I can try?

Here is some (hopefully relevant) output.

`vainfo` (non-root):

```
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_17
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.17 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 23.1.2 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileAV1Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

`lspci | grep VGA` (as root):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)
```

`lshw -class display` (as root):

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:138 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Here is `dmesg` output after plugging into the USB-C port and unplugging it a few seconds after nothing happened on the monitor:

```
[ 5686.669693] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 5686.821688] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=06c4, idProduct=c100, bcdDevice= 0.04
[ 5686.821704] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5686.821710] usb 1-2: Product: DisplayPort ALT mode device
[ 5686.821714] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: BizLink Technology Inc.
[ 5703.299482] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
```